# Search for keywords over a large amount of websites

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, scrape

I am not sure where to start with this problem:

I want to look for keywords in a website that has millions of possible url endings

Example: www.example.com\1384727631

I know that the website increases the url number over time (November 10th 2019 will have a lower url number than December 1st 2020).

How would I write a scrip that looks for the url ending associated with my key word. Say I want to find the url number with the word "Fish" in it?

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to end up with all the webapages that contain the word fish in their bodies?

Comment: Basically, yes I am just not very good at coding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are more likely to get an answer if you describe the steps you have taken to try to solve the problem including the research you've done. See how to ask a good question on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is absolutely not a beginner task, especially if you want a fast algorithm. In case you have tried something already please show the code and its problems